# External 4 drive USB Disk is disconnecting from Windows 10 when left idle for a few minutes

Tags: windows-10, usb, power-management

According to some blog posts I have seen, others are seeing this problem too, and the vendor of the USB hard disks (Mediasonic in this case) claims it's an issue with Windows 8.1 and Windows 10's USB layer.

Behaviour:

1. Attach the four-bay drive and power it up.
2. Let it sit 5-10 minutes.
3. It will power itself completely off.

The model of external USB disk drive case is Mediasonic  PROBOX HF2 SU3S2.

UPDATE: The normal google-able solutions include USB Power management configuration in Windows, which have already been done.  You have to make sure the Power Management settings for the Root Hubs don't make the root hubs go to sleep.     You also have to go to the Power Plan settings in Windows and make sure that when the system has A/C power it's not putting your disks to sleep. THIS HAS BEEN DONE.

UPDATE 2:  Using eventvwr.msc I can see that windows is having huge internal difficulties with the external enclosure.  It looks like Windows is actually signalling the enclosure with some USB event which is causing the device to sleep.  From what I can see, it seems like a bug in windows.

UPDATE 3: After 24 hours the issue has morphed into the drive disconnecting and reconnecting rapidly.

UPDATE 4: It's a physical disk problem (Disk S.M.A.R.T. information shows failure imminent.)

Comment: same or similar question (also asked by me) on mediasonic support forum:
http://forum.mediasonic.ca/viewtopic.php?f=146&t=4028&p=15489#p15489

Comment: Did you try to use extremely short and highest (certified) quality cables, to see if the disconnects are related to overall signal integrity, and not with USB link power management?

Comment: Did you try USB 2.0 -only connection? Do you see same result?

Comment: I found the rapid disconnection issue. The SATA drive in the case was failing, and giving many read timeouts and errors.

Comment: If it powers off it means Windows did not mount the drive within a certain time, or unmounted it again.

Comment: Why you are not answering simple questions?

Comment: Yes I did try USB 2.0. No effect.  I did try several cables. No effect.  After checking S.M.A.R.T. I determined the drive itself was bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific case, the disk was physically failing.  Unfortunately you have to manually check S.M.A.R.T. information using a disk info utility to find this information.  You can also see signs of it in windows event viewer (eventvwr.msc) but no visible indication of disk failure will be shown to you in Windows 10 when such a disk failure is causing the drive to basically error out.  And when it does this, USB enclosures sometimes enter into a situation where after about 30 more seconds they just power off.